# In a batch file, how do I execute a .vbs from the same directory? How do I take parameters?

Tags: batch-file

Very simple question I am sure.

I have a file called ACLReader.vbs which I have written. I want a user to be able to run a batch file

I also want the batch to take a parameter and pass it to ACLReader.vbs instead of using testText.txt (as the user would if execute ACLReader.vbs from the command line)

This is what I have from googling but it doesn't work:

```
%~d0
cd %~p0
cscript ACLReader.vbs testText.txt
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" -> can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
cscript ACLReader.vbs %*
```

Comment: Many thanks, looks like that works (and if it is run from the command line I don't have to find out the directory of the .bat it seems)

Answer (score 1):

To make the CD command in your original script work, you have to change it in the following way:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
cscript ACLReader.vbs %*
```